# Typescript Bug: Extending An Inferred Type Prevents TS Linting Errors (Playground Example Provided)

Tags: typescript, generics, type-inference, typescript-generics

I have a function called `myStyles`, which takes a single argument. This argument is an object containing a `baseStyles` object and a `styleVariants` object. It simply returns the `styleVariants` object.

```
function myStyles<StyleVariants extends StyleVariantsStructure>(params: {
  baseStyles: AllowedStyles;
  styleVariants: StyleVariants;
}): StyleVariants {
  return params.styleVariants;
}
```

It is called like so:

```
myStyles({
  baseStyles: {
    color: 'red',
    backgroundColor: 'red',
  },
  styleVariants: {
    color: {
      red: {
        color: 'red',
        backgroundColor: 'red',
      },
    },
  },
});
```

The `baseStyles` object has the type `AllowedStyles`, which determines which css properties and values we allow. This works perfectly and we get the correct TS errors if the CSS properties or values are misspelled when calling the `myStyles` function e.g.

```
type AllowedStyles = {
  color?: 'red';
  backgroundColor?: 'red';
};
```

The `styleVariants` object has the type `StyleVariantsStructure`. This essentially determines that it should accept one or many nested objects that contain the `AllowedStyles` e.g.

```
type StyleVariantsStructure = {
  [k: string]: {
    [k: string]: AllowedStyles;
  };
};
```

In the `myStyles` function, we use type inference for the `styleVariants` param object. Meaning, we automatically get the exact type of the `styleVariants` passed in to the `myStyles` function. We then use the `styleVariants` type as the return type for the function. This is required for us, because we need to know the exact return type of `myStyles`. Here's our function again:

```
function myStyles<StyleVariants extends StyleVariantsStructure>(params: {
  baseStyles: AllowedStyles;
  styleVariants: StyleVariants;
}): StyleVariants {
  return params.styleVariants;
}
```

And here's an example of the type inference return type, taken from a [Typescript playground I've used to demo this issue](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAggNnA9gdwgEwMqjhAzlAXigG8AoKKAY0SQCcB%20ALigHJb0WBucqAIwENKAawDmtRAFcAdmgDCNRA2ZsO3AL7dSoSFCwgcANX60AlvynBcWWhMrAJ7QiR4BtIc1zBTUkQF1mZBQUbh5eJj7%20sAgo6Ho4uNwUGqTJpABm0nYmiFJQALYgcXgAPEVGpuaWUBAAHsAQMvhlxmYWVl629uwAfAAUYMb8ebgBPAK4EEUjUUiomNh4iVCe%20hDlrZbMzRVt6gCUzhTsXbkDtEO4AHQrhi2VCSmkpAVTvYF8-BNTo0FUCrTKdhoFgAGh4FAEwjEkhk8jogI4YKSSOWC3W9x%20QWo8MOvygQMxeL%20OJUwJRRMhonE0jk-wRZPBQTU5KgzJ4bLUe04QA):

[image]

**The problem**

As you can see, I need to both restrict things being passed in the `styleVariants` object, using the `StyleVariantsStructure` type e.g. we must only accept `AllowedStyles`. However, we also need to use the inferred type from `styleVariants` for the return type of the `myStyles` function. I have attempted to solve this by using `StyleVariants extends StyleVariantsStructure`. This works somewhat, but some Typescript errors aren't highlighted in the `styleVariants` argument object when calling `myStyles`.

For example, if `color` is misspelled, we get no TS error:

[image]

However, I do get type suggestions:

[image]

And, I do get errors if the value is misspelled:

[image]

Essentially, to me, it seems like I need to find an alternate way to use type inference for the `styleVariants` object, whilst also restricting it using the `StyleVariantsStructure` type. Any help on this would be much appreciated.

[Minimal demo of the issue in Typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAggNnA9gdwgEwMqjhAzlAXigG8AoKKAY0SQCcB%20ALigHJb0WBucqAIwENKAawDmtRAFcAdmgDCNRA2ZsO3AL7dSoSFCwgcANX60AlvynBcWWhMrAJ7QiR4BtIc1zBTUkQF1mZBQUbh5eJj7%20sAgo6Ho4uNwUGqTJpABm0nYmiFJQALYgcXgAPEVGpuaWUBAAHsAQMvhlxmYWVl629uwAfAAUYMb8ebgBPAK4EEUjUUiomNh4iVCe%20hDlrZbMzRVt6gCUzhTsXbkDtEO4AHQrhi2VCSmkpAVTvYF8-BNTo0FUCrTKdhoFgAGh4FAEwjEkhk8jogI4YKSSOWC3W9x%20QWo8MOvygQMxeL%20OJUwJRRMhonE0jk-wRZPBQTU5KgzJ4bLUe04QA)

Comment: Did I get you right, you want to provide to `baseStyles` color values that will be used in `styleVariants` as a key? If yes, `style.styleVariants.color[style.baseStyles.color]` also should suit the same structure as `style.styleVariants`

Comment: @MikeKokadii Thanks for the reply. Unfortunately that's not what I'm looking for. I simply want to be able to apply the StyleVariantsStructure type to the styleVariants object, and be able to get the correct TS listing errors if I misspell 'color' (for example). If you check out the Typescript playground the issue might be clearer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strictly speaking, this looks correct, but TS needs to be coaxed into checking it. For example, wrapping the call in the playground with console.log() generates the typechecking you want.

TS is imperfect as a checker, so it can take some finagling for it to detect the "right" solution in highly complex situations - which this is!

Comment: This is indeed correct. If you wrap the myStyles function call in another function call (or console.log), the type checking works as intended. This is an interesting observation.

Answer (score 0):

I spend more time on it than I expected, but here we are.

If you need to highlighting typo, you should based StyleVariants on AllowedStyles, for example:

```
type AllowedStyles = {
  color: 'red' | 'green';
  backgroundColor: 'red';
};

type StyleVariants = {
  [K in keyof AllowedStyles]?: AllowedStyles[K] | Partial<Record<AllowedStyles[K], Partial<AllowedStyles>>>
}

type StyleVariantsStructure = {
  baseStyles: AllowedStyles
  styleVariants: StyleVariants
}

function myStyles(params: StyleVariantsStructure):StyleVariants {
  return params.styleVariants;
}
```

StyleVariants based on AllowedStyles structure and values, it contains every property AllowedStyles has, but they are optional. The type of every property is provided in AllowedStyles type of property respectively OR it is an object which keys is each of provided types in AllowedStyles to property and its type is again AllowedStyles with all property being optional. Hope you get it!

[Typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAggNnA9gdwgEwMqjhAzlAXigG8AoKKAY0SQCcAuKAclvSagB9mBzViAOyYBuclABGAQ0oBrXogCu-NAGEaiBs1ZphpAL4jSoSFCwgcANQm0AlhP7B8RMhQDaAaSjX%20UaRBCIAM1gEFHRTHFwAXQB%20RngkVExsPHdIzigABStgWzgAHgAlCGpaNDz40KSzFLdIgBpM7NzykMTwvAA%20Lr1SQ3BodssbOwcsWnlKYHlWQhJRSVwIdtw41rDk3FFcZKHbexWTHas9hx7SAMVJ60RvAFsQZYAKMCsJW4PB45HcMYmp1gAlPRPsN9nMKKx-t4XrQ3rgAHTbaq7b4iXS9e5PZziCSLZaMbEUah0RgsNh1UQUSQyOSKFRqDRk7QUii6FlQJEWL77AmUqgM3kUIVQXgQASC4VC4nqRgAIi0svZwrZfJVwupsloCiUqhJUHl6EVohVugBQiAA)

Comment: Thanks for your reply Mike. Unfortunately in your example (judging by the Playground), we loose the type inference for the return type (see the first picture I attached to my original question). I'll have a look at your implementation a little more in depth tonight however